# Check if a string contains any file extension whatsoever

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-extension

I'm sure this is a simple thing to do but I don't know how. What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
templateFilename = str( templateFilename )

# If no file extension is found, assume it is a .npy file
if templateFilename.endswith( '.*' ):
    templateFilename += ".npy"
```

However, this syntax doesn't seem to work. I want the `*` to represent any file extension so that, if the parsed file does contain a file extension, that one will be used but, if not, a standard extension will be added.

I have read about the `glob` module and people seem to be using that for finding things such as `*.txt`, etc. but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Does having any extension just amount to the filename containing a `.` character?

Comment: Make a list of the authorize file extension and then check if the str last characters are in the list (split at the dot). If not, then add the specified file extension.

Comment: try `import re`

Comment: @Mathieu, I think this may be a smart way to go about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest `os.path.splitext`. The following uses `.npy` as the extension if none exists:

```
root, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
if not ext:
   ext = '.npy'
path = root + ext
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

(Speaking from experience and hair-loss)

Doing a split on `.` and then selecting the second element `[1]` will only work if you can absolutely guarantee that there are no `.` in the filename; otherwise you'll need something like this:

```
file_extension = [".csv", ".xml", ".html"]

if '.' in templateFilename:      #checks if you can actually split, if you can't perform a split; you would raise an index error.
    if templateFilename.split(".")[-1] in file_extension:    #[-1] = the last element in the list.
        has_extension = true
        has_verified_extension = true
    else:
        has_extension = true
        has_verified_extension = false
else:            #no '.'. in the filename, so no extension.
    has_extension = false
```

Comment: If there is the risk that `.` appears in the file name, simply make a recursive function that takes the right part of a string splitted at the `.` until there is no more `.` in the right part. You'll get the file's extension everytime ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
file_extension = [".pyo", ".npy", ".py"]
templateFilename = str( templateFilename )  
# If no file extension is found, assume it is a .npy file
if not templateFilename.split(".")[1]  in file_extension:
    templateFilename += ".npy"
```

Comment: Having thought about this, I don't think it would work. The people in my field save things as all kinds of nonsensical file extensions that they like to use (but usually they are just disguised np arrays)

Answer (score 0):

If you want in one line then here it is :

```
templatefilename = "abcd"    
non_ext_file_list = [filename + ".npy" for filename in templateFilename.split(".") if not "." in templateFilename]

#output 
[abcd.npy]
```